# How to pass variables (from Object of type Class) to functions (in the main.cpp) as an object only

Tags: c++

I have a class(A) that contains for example five variables (parameters t,z,y,d and f) and I created an object(A) of a type class(A). Then I have many functions (X,U,M) that are included in the "main.cpp", each function is defined to take only three or four parameters that are already exist in the object(A). for example function(X) uses the variables (t,y and z only)

Instead of passing the parameters as `void function(X) (int t, int y, double z){}` can I pass only the object(A) and let each function selects its parameters by just looking for what it needs from object(A)'s parameters as follow (if this exist)?

```
    void function(X) (A()){}
```

I would like to avoid using the following.

```
    void function(X) (A.t, A.y, A.z){}
```

(Please note I am new to c++ and I am working in Qt Creator.)

Comment: If t, y and z are public it's pretty easy: declare int t = A.t ,etc in your function ; or use A.t the same way you would use t. If t,y and z are private you need to create accesors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joachim's explanation is what you need, except that the object should be passed as either a pointer or a reference, to ensure it isn't getting copied.

```
void someFunction(C& c)
    // Accept a reference to a 'C' object
{
    // Joachim's code
    // This method doesn't change the main from Joachim's
    // answer.
}

void someFunction(C* c)
    // Accept a pointer to a 'C' object
{
    std::cout << "The member i_ is " << c->getI() << std::endl;
    // Note the use of '->', not '.' to access the object's method.
}

void main()
{
     C c;
     c.setI(1);

     someFunction(&c);
     // The '&' means 'address of' in this context. I.E. you're passing a pointer.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can pass an object to a function. There are several ways to pass the an instance of a class to a function:

- **by value** (if `function()` needs to modify `obj` but the caller does not need to see the changes and copying is inexpensive):

  ```
  void function(A obj) {}
  ```
- **by reference** (if `function()` modifies `obj` and changes must be visible to the caller):

  ```
  void function(A& obj) {}
  ```
- **by `const` reference** (if `function()` does not modify `obj`):

  ```
  void function(A const& obj) {}
  ```
- **by rvalue reference** (c++11):

  ```
  void function(A&& obj) {}
  ```

The `class A` will need to provide access to it's members.

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
class A
{
public:
    double z;
};

void func(const A &obj)
{
    // Do something with obj.z
    std::cout << obj.z << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A myObj;

    myObj.z = 100;

    func(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the member fields are `public` you can access them from any function. If the are not `public` you have to add member functions to the class to get the values, so called "getter" functions.

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    int getI() const { return i_; }
    void setI(const int i) { i_ = i; }

private:
    int i_;
}

void someFunction(C c)
{
    std::cout << "The member i_ in c is " << c.getI() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.setI(123);

    someFunction(c);
}
```